# Trying to do simple do_operation function in C

Tags: c, operators, operation

I'm going a bit crazy trying to a very simple operation function in C as a beginner, but it seems everything I try failed, although it's supposed to work.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int     calcul(int nb1, int nb2, char *av)
{
        int nb = 0;
        if (av[2] == '*')
                nb = nb1 * nb2;
        if (av[2] == '%')
                nb = nb1 % nb2;
        if (av[2] == '/')
                nb = nb1 / nb2;
        if (av[2] == '+')
                nb = nb1 + nb2;
        if (av[2] == '-')
                nb = nb1 - nb2;
        return (nb);
}

int     atoi();

int     main(int ac, char **av)
{
        printf("%s", av[2]);
        if (ac == 4)
                printf("%d", calcul(atoi(av[1]), atoi(av[3]), av[2]));
        return (0);
}
```

It seems like at soon as the second argument, which is the operator, goes through the `calcul` function, it change the actual character into either it's ASCII value or something else, thus not being detected properly in the condition.

I've tried to fiddle many ways and look up other snippet, but this is exactly what they were doing and how it's supposed to work (even if I remove the `printf`), so what am I doing wrong?

**EDIT** Sorry I purposely change the number of argument to get a segfault for something else, here's the "correct" function I'm testing for which I'm getting the problem.

Also the way I'm using this function is by running a simple compiled prog under this format in shell:

```
./a.out 2 * 3
```

**SOLVED** As @Mike pointed out when entering the calculate function, av[2] which is the operator was now considered the first and only character argument, therefor was to be identified with av[0]. Which is a little confusing/tricky.

Comment: If you are using a shell, it may be interpreting your operator as a pattern, and substituting in an expansion on you when you get it in your program.

Comment: How exactly is this program supposed to be called?

Comment: it also appears you are accessing beyond the `char **av` array. If `ac==4`, then the only valid indices for `av` are 0 through 3.

Comment: Do not define `atoi()` yourself.  It should be defined in `<stdlib.h>` already.

Comment: If you are using the program arguments, the very first thing you should do is check how many. But you leave that until *after* you use `av[2]`, and even then `av[4]` might be out of range of the check `if (ac == 4)` since `av[4]` requires *at least* 5 arguments.

Comment: @yano yup, I copied the wrong version, I update with the corrected one for which I'm trying to fix the result.

Comment: @chqrlie that's what I'm doing here it seems to me.

Comment: @jxh could you elaborate. I'm using a shell, so it's reading the operator as a pointer to the second argument which should only be the first character presented as such: ./a.out 3 + 5

Comment: what does `printf("%s\n", av[2]);` output?

Comment: @yazze: `int atoi();` is a declaration for `atoi()`. Remove this line.

Comment: @chqrlie indeed, it's useless, thx.

Comment: @yano it outputs the correct operator entered as a character (so the first of the string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have your indexing wrong. I changed the code a bit assuming that you wanted to print the operator character to make sure it was working.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int     calcul(int nb1, int nb2, char *av)
{
        int nb = 0;
        printf("%c\n", av[0]);
        if (av[0] == '*')
                nb = nb1 * nb2;
        if (av[0] == '%')
                nb = nb1 % nb2;
        if (av[0] == '/')
                nb = nb1 / nb2;
        if (av[0] == '+')
                nb = nb1 + nb2;
        if (av[0] == '-')
                nb = nb1 - nb2;
        return (nb);
}

int     main(int ac, char **av)
{
        printf("%s\n", av[2]);
        if (ac == 4)
                printf("%d\n", calcul(atoi(av[1]), atoi(av[3]), av[2]));
        return (0);
}
```

Notice in your `calcul` funciton you were calling `av[2]` which is the trying to get the third index of a string containing just your operator character which is NULL.

ETA:

Also a note on the `*` operator. To get it to work you need to call it with an escape character `\`.

ETA2:

Changed the code to match the edits in the answer so it can be called with:

```
./a 3 + 4
./a 3 '*' 9
```

Comment: You can also using single quotes: around the asterisk when calling the program `calculate  '*'` 5 4

Comment: I'm compiling and running the program under this form:

./a.out 2 * 3

So the operator should be the av[2] yet it's not reading it.

Comment: @yazze Simple fix. Change the line calcul(atoi(av[3]), atoi(av[2]), av[1])) to back to calcul(atoi(av[1]), atoi(av[3]), av[2])) with the same code in the answer and change the printf statements accordingly to show 'av[2]'. However, keep the 'av[0]' statement as is in the if statements.

Comment: @yaze It depends on the shell if you need to escape the asterisk. If you compile for wirndows using mingw and use the command prompt you don't need it. Further there are a lot shells for Unix out there. You can't thell for sure that all of them expand the asterisk to anything. -- Further neither the OS nor the shell is specified. -- Further more it's not asked.

Comment: @Mike This worked. Why did the argument number had to change. Is the av[2] entered as parameter now considered the av[0] for some reasons? Why is that?

Comment: @harper I will use 'x' instead of '*' in the input for multiplication to keep it simple.

Answer (score 0):

Just a follow up to your question in the comments...

Arguments are passed to `c` programs as an array of strings; that is, a list of strings.  A `c` string is a list of characters, so a list of strings is 2-d array or matrix of characters.  Each string has an index.  Each `char` within a string has an index  You can visualize it as a grid:

```
                           Index of char in string
                         _|_0_|_1_|_2_|_3_|_4_|_5_| ... etc
                         0|___|___|___|___|___|___|___
                         1|___|___|___|___|___|___|___
                         2|___|___|___|___|___|___|___
Index of string in list  3|___|___|___|___|___|___|___
                         4|___|___|___|___|___|___|___
                         5|___|___|___|___|___|___|___
                        ... etc
```

So if you call your program `./a.out 3 '*' 9`, `char** av` will contain 4 strings:

```
av[0] = "a.out"
av[1] = "3"
av[2] = "*"
av[3] = "9"
```

Of course, `c` strings are NULL-terminated, so in the grid view, you would see

```
                           Index of char in string
                         _|_0_|_1_|_2_|_3_|_4_|_5_| ... etc
                         0|_a_|_._|_o_|_u_|_t_|\0_|___
                         1|_3_|\0_|___|___|___|___|___
                         2|_*_|\0_|___|___|___|___|___
Index of string in list  3|_9_|\0_|___|___|___|___|___
                         4|___|___|___|___|___|___|___
                         5|___|___|___|___|___|___|___    
                        ... etc
```

The first character of each string begins at index 0; for example, string 0, char 0 is 'a', or

```
av[0][0] = 'a'
av[1][0] = '3'
av[2][0] = '*'
av[3][0] = '9'
```

So when you pass `av[2]` to your function, you are passing a `char*` to the entire 3rd-string argument (which in this case only consists of 1 `char`, the `*` character).  Therefore, in the `calcul` function Mike is correctly checking the first `char` of the string, which is where the operator resides.  In the `calcul` function, `av[1]` contains the string-terminator NULL byte `\0`, and `av[2]` and higher are undefined indices.  I would recommend changing the name of the `av` argument in the `calcul` function to something else so you don't confuse it with the `av` argument from main.

Just remember, in this instance, `char** av` is a list of strings (where each index 0, 1, 2, etc, addresses a string in that list, and `char* av` is a single string (where each index 0, 1, 2, etc, addresses a character in that string).